# Meteor: how to test packages with jasmine tests on travis-ci?

Tags: meteor, travis-ci, meteor-velocity

I have a meteor package and it contains some tests written using velocity and jasmine. I tried to follow the descriptions in https://github.com/arunoda/travis-ci-meteor-packages to add Travis CI support. However, it seems from the log file that no test actually got run.

```
node start_test.js
I20150818-06:28:58.169(0)? test-in-console listening
starting testing...
Running Meteor tests in PhantomJS... http://localhost:10015/
Running Jasmine tests
passed/expected/failed/total 0 / 0 / 0 / 0
##_meteor_magic##state: done
The command "make test" exited with 0.
Done. Your build exited with 0.
```

The log file mentions Jasmine tests, so it recognizes the tests. But it reports zero tests

```
passed/expected/failed/total 0 / 0 / 0 / 0
```

Is it true that the instructions in https://github.com/arunoda/travis-ci-meteor-packages only works for tiny tests?

The .travis.yml file I use is:
https://github.com/sf-wind/meteor-template-elements/blob/master/.travis.yml

Any step I missed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OK. I end up using velocity cli to perform the tests. I put up a github repository to include the scripts used: https://github.com/sf-wind/meteor-velocity-travis-ci

Hope it helps.